# Limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

So it's given that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = a$$ also $a\neq 0$.
I need to prove, using the definition of the limit $$\forall\epsilon\geqslant0.\exists n_\epsilon\in \mathbb{N}.\forall n>n_\epsilon.|a_n-L|<\epsilon$$
that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$$
I tried saying that if $\forall\epsilon\geqslant0.\exists n_\epsilon\in \mathbb{N}.\forall n>n_\epsilon.|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ then, $a-\epsilon\leqslant a_n \leqslant a+\epsilon$ and the same for $a_{n+1}$: $a-\epsilon\leqslant a_{n+1}\leqslant a+\epsilon$, then
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right|=\left|\frac{a+\epsilon}{a-\epsilon}-1\right|=\left|\frac{a+\epsilon-a+\epsilon}{a-\epsilon}\right|=\left|\frac{2\epsilon}{a-\epsilon}\right|$$
I don't know if what I did was right, but I also don't know where to go from here, I would appreciate hints or guidance.

Comment: Note that this is not valid if $a=0$, e.g. if $a_{2n}=1/n$ and $a_{2n-1}=1/2^n.$ So a proof for $a\ne 0$ must make use of the premise $a\ne 0$ somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1 \right|=\left|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}\right|$. Assume that $a_n \to a \neq 0$ so $|a_n| \to |a|>0$. Then for sufficiently large $n$, it follows that $|a_n|>\frac{|a|}{2}$ (why?). For the numerator, consider that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ must be Cauchy since it converges.

Comment: I get that it's Cauchy, but I need to solve the question using the definition of the limit, using epsilon

Comment: I'm suggesting the following idea: Since $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$, we have $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$. Choose $m=n+1$. Then it follows that for all $n\geq N$, we have $|a_n-a_{n+1}|<\epsilon$. In other words, use the fact that the sequence is Cauchy to obtain this $N$. This is helpful for proving convergence in the problem.

Comment: To be slightly more elegant, you may want to choose $N$ so that $|a_n-a_m|<\frac{2}{|a|}\epsilon$. Based on my answer, how do you put this together?

Comment: I'll try to think of it this way, thank you